# DICOM OB-GYN measurements

Tags: dicom

I'm a new in dicom area. I have to create small tool, that convert dicom file to simple pdf report. This report should contains just patient info, some measurement and picture(s). In documentation I found that all information in dicom file stores based on tage, like tag1-value1, tag2-value2. Using external library, I found the way how to pull patient info and pixel data. But I stuck with measurement. I didn't find tags that I need or may be there is a different way how data stores in dicom file.

So my questions are:

1. Does the dicom file that comes from ultrasound machine contain ob-gyn measurements like HC (Head circumference), AC (Abdominal circumference), BPD (Biparietal diameter) and others?
2. In what tag/section is this information contained?

Thanks for any help or useful links to read.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a DICOM Structured Reporting (SR) object coming from the ultrasound machine, the measurements will probably be stored according to the SR Template [TID 5000](http://dicom.nema.org/MEDICAL/Dicom/current/output/chtml/part16/sect_OB-GYNReportTemplates.html). You should have a look at the DICOM Conformance Statement of the machine to check this out.

You can make the content of such an SR document "human-readable" by a tool like [dsrdump](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/dsrdump.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, I don't have direct contact to any physician or hospital. My friend gave we few "real" dicom files from hospotal with images, but non of them contain measurements. Ok, will try to get few SR file from him. May be SR is an answer where measurements are. But still I confused why image dicom do not contains this info.

Comment: In a perfect DICOM world, image objects are for images only. Measurements should be stored as SR objects (see above) containing UID references to the image objects. Of course, there are systems out there that use privately extended DICOM images and/or other proprietary means of storing the measurements...

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks. But out of topic, when I read about dicom, I thought the main idea is store all patient info(personal, study, measurements) and images in one file. Instead use, let say, jpg or png for image and other info in work or pdf file, to avoid any mistakes. May be I got it wrong. I will look on SR closer. Thank you.

Comment: The main idea is to store all information in one (standard) FORMAT, not in one file :) Also, all information is available from the PACS (and associated systems) using the DICOM standard network services...

Comment: Yeah, if mean one format it makes more sense for me. Thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The files contain the information if the sonographer entered the measurments.

Look at the documentation about Structured Reporting to see how the data is accessed. (eg - http://www.dclunie.com/pixelmed/DICOMSR.book.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for reply and for link. As I understand SR files are another dicom files "type", but have different structure and don't have pixel data. SR comes from ultrasound machine and I contains all measurement, of course if sonographer entered it during procedure. Am I right?

Comment: It's been a few years since I looked, but I'm pretty sure that the measurements are included in the image file. I'll grab one this eventing and do a dump. If you have some image files use a dicom dump tool to see the contents. You'll see the measurement data and associated tags in there.

Comment: I grabbed a couple of images from a LogiqS8 tonight and none of the measurements appeared in the data. I'll ask the sales rep if it's an add on.

Comment: Thanks, John. I have few image file, but none of it contains measurements when I open it in dump tools.

Comment: Yes, I think that you were right above, the measurements come over in SR files, not in the image files.